# VBA - If row contains value then enter data in to corresponding cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a macro button which when pressed will read the value in a data entry cell, search for the row with the exact match in and then edit the cell in that row but in a different column.

```
+--------+-------------------------+--------+
| Number |          Name           | Status |
+--------+-------------------------+--------+
|      0 | Panini Special Sticker  | Got    |
|      1 | Fifa Fair Play          | Need   |
|      2 | Logo/1                  | Got    |
|      3 | Logo/2                  | Need   |
|      4 | Mascot/1                | Got    |
|      5 | Mascot/2                | Got    |
|      6 | Trophy                  | Need   |
|      7 | Official Ball           | Got    |
|      8 | Stadium Belo Horizonte1 | Got    |
|      9 | Stadium Belo Horizonte2 | Need   |
|     10 | Stadium Brasília1       | Got    |
+--------+-------------------------+--------+
```

So if i enter "7" into the data entry box and then click the button, it will find and select row 9 and then change the value of cell C9 to "Swap"

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: I think I can find the row but its after that I'm unsure

Comment: <code>
    Sub AddGot()
    Sheets("GotGotNeed").Select
    row_number = 1

    Do
    DoEvents
        rownumber = row_number + 1
        playerNumber = GotGotNeed: Range ("A" & row_number)
        
        If InStr(playerNumber, Enter_Number_Needed) >= 1 Then
            
            End If
            
    Loop Until playerNumber = ""
    
    MsgBox = "Completed"
       
    
    End Sub
    </code>

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, it's also unnecessary to use markup tags like `<html>` and `<code>`, the editor does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so if I understand you correctly, you need to take the input from a cell (can this be on change or specifically when the button is clicked?), find the row in Column A with the matching value on a different sheet, then change that row's Column C value to "Swap".

Try this (this fires off when the data entry cell changes):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim entryCell       As Range:   Set entryCell = Me.Range("A1") '' change this to the address of your data entry cell

    If Not Intersect(Target, entryCell) Is Nothing Then FindMatch (entryCell.Value)

End Sub

Private Sub FindMatch(ByVal cellInput As String)

    Dim searchSheet     As Worksheet:   Set searchSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") '' change this to the name of the sheet you search for the value on
    Dim searchRange     As Range:       Set searchRange = searchSheet.Range("A1:A" & searchSheet.Range("A" & searchSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim found           As Range

    Set found = searchRange.Find(cellInput, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        found.Offset(, 2).Value = "Swap"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found in 'searchRange'"
    End If

End Sub
```

You would put this in the worksheet module that your data entry cell is on. This is probably the best way to do it but if you need to tie a macro to a command button you can change the Worksheet_Change subroutine to:

```
Private Sub ButtonClick()

    Dim entryCell       As Range:   Set entryCell = Me.Range("A1") '' change this to the address of your data entry cell

    FindMatch (entryCell.Value)

End Sub
```

And then tie the click event of your button to `ButtonClick()`